# High quality example code for a Java EE application using Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, open-source, projects-and-solutions

What are some open source Spring MVC 3 projects which I can download that implement many best-practices and have a relatively high code quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-in-3-samples) references for detailed features and links on spring MVC3 . You can also find the samples SVN [here](https://anonsvn.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/). Check out the PetClinic/ samples .

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at [Spring MVC showcases](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase).
Also there are a lot of different open source projects, just look for 'spring mvc' in github - and you'll find them.